# Using switch statement showing different message when hours changed in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement

It work well on if/else statement, but once use switch statement and the default message is display only even my local time is less than 24 (12am). Thanks for help in advance as always.

```js
  var today = new Date();
  var timeNow = today.getHours()
  var greeting = $("#greeting");

switch (timeNow) {
    case timeNow > 17 : greeting = "Good Evening </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    case timeNow > 12 : greeting = "Good Afternoon </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    case timeNow > 6 : greeting = "Good Morning </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    default: greeting = "Welcome... but isn't it bed time now?";
  }

  $('#greeting').html('<h1>' + greeting + '<h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="greeting">Welcome!</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `switch` statement is trying to compare the value of `timeNow` against the *result* of `timeNow > 17` and such, which will be a boolean (`true` or `false`). Naturally, none of the will match, because no `Date` instance is `===` either `true` or `false`.

Your original `if/else if/else` was probably the right way to go.

However, you *can* use `switch` for this in JavaScript (unlike many other languages), because the `case` values can be *expressions*, and they're evaluated in source code order with only the first matching one being used (other than `default`, which is always used last if none of the others matches). So if you change

```
switch (timeNow) {
```

to

```
switch (true) {
```

...then that `true` is compared with the result of `timeNow > 17` and such:

```js
var today = new Date();
  var timeNow = today.getHours()
  var greeting = $("#greeting");

switch (true) { // <=== Change is here
    case timeNow > 17 : greeting = "Good Evening </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    case timeNow > 12 : greeting = "Good Afternoon </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    case timeNow > 6 : greeting = "Good Morning </br> Welcome To My Website";
    break;
    default: greeting = "Welcome... but isn't it bed time now?";
  }

  $('#greeting').html('<h1>' + greeting + '<h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="greeting">Welcome!</h1>
```

**Again**, though: Your original `if/else if/else` was probably the right way to go.

Comment: (Realized this was almost certainly a duplicate and found an earlier version, so I converted the above to a CW.)

Answer (score 2):

Switch case only perform equality test (==) like `case 23:`